# There are some solutions in a lab which can be either acid, alkaline or neutral. Given some clues, try to find the probability.

Tags: probability

> Solutions can be either acid, alkaline or neutral. The aqueous
>   solutions in a lab have been studied in regards to their pH and their
>   wavelenght absorption.
>
> The following conclusions were made:
>
> - $40$% of the solutions are alkaline, $40$% are acid and the rest are neutral;
> - $25$% of the acid solutions absorb in the wavelenght of red;
> - $5$% of the solutions are neutral and absorb in the wavelenght of red;
> - the probability that a solution absorbs in the wavelenght of red is $0.2$
>
> Picking a solution randomly, find the probability that the solution:
>
> 1. is not acid nor alkaline and doesn't absorb in the wavelenght of red;
> 2. absorbs in the wavelenght of red, knowing it is alkaline;
> 3. isn't neutral and doesn't absorb in the wavelenght of red.

Using just this information, I made a diagram:

[image]

(R means Red, NR means Not Red)

I can find the probability that the solution is alkaline and red by doing:

$$(.4\cdot.25)+.05+ R = .2\Leftrightarrow \\
R = .05$$

Then I do:

$$.05 = .4\cdot x \Leftrightarrow x = .02$$

And so the updated diagram becomes:

[image]

Finally I tried answering:

1. $.2\cdot .75 = .15$
2. $.02$
3. $(.4\cdot(.4\cdot.75))+(.4\cdot(.4\cdot.98))=.2768$

My book states 1. is correct but 2. and 3. are not (they are $12.5$% and $65$% respectively ). What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x$ you found is not correct:

$$P(R|alkaline) = \frac{P(R\cap alkaline)}{P(alkaline)} = \frac{.05}{.4} = .125$$